# How can I bind multiple elements to multiple events in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a form called `#regForm` and a `div` called `regDiv`. If you either submit the form or click the div, I want to fire an event.

`$(document).on('#regForm, .regDiv', 'click submit', function(e) {`

doesn't seem to work.

Comment: $(document).on('click submit', '#regForm, .regDiv', function(e) {

Comment: Why a downvote for this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
$(document).on('click submit', '#regForm, .regDiv', function(e) {
   //place your code
});
```

[**`.on()`**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) should be like

> **.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler(eventObject) )**